# Improvement of Python code array of sub-arrays sum of square divisors

Tags: python, arrays, math

This question from cw asks for a function that takes two integers and returns an array of two element arrays each consisting of an integer and the sum of their squared divisors. The array must include only the sub-arrays whose integer is in range of the two provided integers(m,n) and that they correspond to perfect square as the sum of their squared divisors.

I have attempted the following code below and it returns the correct answer to pass the sample tests, but it runs too slow to pass the rest of the tests.

I would appreciate any suggestions to improve efficiency

```
import math

def is_square(integer):
    root = math.sqrt(integer)
    if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 == integer: 
        return True
    else:
        return False

def list_squared(m, n):
    output_numbers= []
    for N in range(m,n+1):
        div_list = [n for n in range(1,N+1) if N % n == 0]
        sum_sq_div = sum([x**2 for x in div_list])
        if is_square(sum_sq_div)==True:
          output_numbers.append([N,sum_sq_div])
    return output_numbers


In [19]: list_squared(1,2000)
[[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100], [287, 84100], [728, 722500], [1434, 2856100], [1673, 2856100], [1880, 4884100]]
```

Comment: What is "cw" in your first sentence?

Comment: the code wars training site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classical waste of CPU power is this line:

```
div_list = [n for n in range(1,N+1) if N % n == 0]
```

Ok it's a list comprehension, but

- it always computes if 1 or `N` divide `N` which is always true
- it loops until `N` which is unnecessary and wasteful if `N` is big: just range until square root, and add the complementary divisor

like this:

```
for n in range(2,int((N+1)**0.5)+1):
    if N % n == 0:
        div_list.append(n)
        opposite = N//n
        if n != opposite: # avoid duplicate if square
            div_list.append(opposite)
```

This reduces the complexity from `O(N)` to `O(N**0.5)`.

With a value of `20000`, your code runs in 28 seconds, with the above modification, it runs in 0.4 seconds, with the same results of course!

Aside: `sum_sq_div = sum([x**2 for x in div_list])` could avoid building the listcomp: `sum_sq_div = sum(x**2 for x in div_list)` is slightly faster.

Also: more pythonic code for `is_square`

```
def is_square(integer):
    return int(math.sqrt(integer) + 0.5) ** 2 == integer:
```